# return a value T from struct in rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a double linked binary tree in rust, and I have some problems when I try to implement functions to return a specific value from a node to replace it in a node that contain the value that I want to delete. This is my code :

```
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T> {
    root: Link<T>
}

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    prev: Link<T>,
    right: Link<T>,
    left: Link<T>
}

impl<T: Ord+ Debug> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, prev: Link<T>, right: Link<T>, left: Link<T>) -> Self {
        Node {
            value: value,
            prev: prev,
            right: right,
            left: left
        }
    }

    //fn get_prev(&mut self, value: &T) -> Link<T> {
        //if value > &self.value {
            //return self.right.clone();
        //}else {
            //return self.left.clone();
        //}
    //}

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T, prev: Link<T>) {
        if value == self.value { return; }
        if value > self.value {
            if self.right.is_none() {
                let mut node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, prev, None, None))));
                self.right = node;
            }else {
                let mut prev_current = self.right.clone();
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev_current);
                });
            }
        }else {
            if self.left.is_none() {
                let mut node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, prev, None, None))));
                self.left = node;
            }else {
                let mut prev_current = self.left.clone();
                self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev_current);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    fn print_prev(&self){
        println!("{:?}", self.value);
    }

    fn print_tree(&self) {
        println!("------");
        println!("{:?}", self.value);
        if (!self.prev.is_none()){
            self.prev.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_prev();
            });
        }
        if (!self.right.is_none()) {
            self.right.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        }
        if (!self.left.is_none()) {
            self.left.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        }
    }

    fn set_prev_none(&mut self, value: &T) {
        if value > &self.value {
            self.right = None;
        }else {
            self.left = None;
        }
    }

    fn set_prev_node(&mut self, value: &T, node: Link<T>){
        if value > &self.value {
            self.right = node;
        }else {
            self.left = node;
        }
    }

    fn find_left_none(&mut self) -> T {
        if (self.left.is_none() && self.right.is_none()) {
            let mut value = &self.value;
            self.prev.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_none(value);
            });
            return self.value;
        }else {
            return (**self.left.as_mut().unwrap().borrow_mut()).borrow_mut().find_left_none();
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T) {
        if self.value == value {
            if self.right.is_none() && self.left.is_none() {
                let mut temp_val = &self.value;
                self.prev.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_none(temp_val);
                }); 
            }else if(self.right.is_none() ^ self.left.is_none()) {
                let mut prev_temp = self.prev.clone(); 
                let mut temp_val = &self.value;
                let mut temp_next = None;
                if self.right.is_none(){
                    temp_next = self.right.clone();
                    self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                        (**node).borrow_mut().prev = prev_temp.clone();
                    });
                }else {
                    temp_next = self.left.clone();
                    self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                        (**node).borrow_mut().prev = prev_temp.clone();
                    });
                }
                prev_temp.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_node(temp_val, temp_next);
                });
            }else {
                let mut val: Option<T> = None;
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    val = Some((**node).borrow_mut().find_left_none());
                });
                self.value = val.unwrap();
            }
        }else {
            if value > self.value {
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
                });
            }else {
                self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord+Debug> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Tree {
            root: None
        }
    }

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T) {
        if self.root.is_none() {
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, None, None, None))));
        }else {
            let mut prev = self.root.clone();
            self.root.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev);
            });
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T){
        if !self.root.is_none() {
            self.root.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
            });
        }
    }

    fn print_tree(&self) {
        if !self.root.is_none() {
            self.root.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        }else {
            println!("empty");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::new();
    tree.insert_value(5);
    tree.insert_value(1);
    tree.insert_value(7);
    tree.insert_value(4);
    tree.insert_value(5);
    tree.print_tree();
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.value` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> .\tree-double.rs:107:20
    |
107 |             return self.value;
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.value` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How I can return the value or clone it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T: Clone> {
    root: Link<T>,
}

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

// you can restrict T to be Cloneable
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T: Clone> {
    value: T,
    prev: Link<T>,
    right: Link<T>,
    left: Link<T>,
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug + Clone> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, prev: Link<T>, right: Link<T>, left: Link<T>) -> Self {
        Node {
            value: value,
            prev: prev,
            right: right,
            left: left,
        }
    }

    //fn get_prev(&mut self, value: &T) -> Link<T> {
    //if value > &self.value {
    //return self.right.clone();
    //}else {
    //return self.left.clone();
    //}
    //}

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T, prev: Link<T>) {
        if value == self.value {
            return;
        }
        if value > self.value {
            if self.right.is_none() {
                let mut node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, prev, None, None))));
                self.right = node;
            } else {
                let mut prev_current = self.right.clone();
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev_current);
                });
            }
        } else {
            if self.left.is_none() {
                let mut node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, prev, None, None))));
                self.left = node;
            } else {
                let mut prev_current = self.left.clone();
                self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev_current);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    fn print_prev(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.value);
    }

    fn print_tree(&self) {
        println!("------");
        println!("{:?}", self.value);
        if (!self.prev.is_none()) {
            self.prev.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_prev();
            });
        }
        if (!self.right.is_none()) {
            self.right.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        }
        if (!self.left.is_none()) {
            self.left.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        }
    }

    fn set_prev_none(&mut self, value: &T) {
        if value > &self.value {
            self.right = None;
        } else {
            self.left = None;
        }
    }

    fn set_prev_node(&mut self, value: &T, node: Link<T>) {
        if value > &self.value {
            self.right = node;
        } else {
            self.left = node;
        }
    }

    fn find_left_none(&mut self) -> T {
        if (self.left.is_none() && self.right.is_none()) {
            let mut value = &self.value;
            self.prev.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_none(value);
            });
            // you need clone the value before return, otherwise T must implement Copy trait, because 
            return self.value.clone();
        } else {
            return (**self.left.as_mut().unwrap().borrow_mut())
                .borrow_mut()
                .find_left_none();
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T) {
        if self.value == value {
            if self.right.is_none() && self.left.is_none() {
                let mut temp_val = &self.value;
                self.prev.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_none(temp_val);
                });
            } else if (self.right.is_none() ^ self.left.is_none()) {
                let mut prev_temp = self.prev.clone();
                let mut temp_val = &self.value;
                let mut temp_next = None;
                if self.right.is_none() {
                    temp_next = self.right.clone();
                    self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                        (**node).borrow_mut().prev = prev_temp.clone();
                    });
                } else {
                    temp_next = self.left.clone();
                    self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                        (**node).borrow_mut().prev = prev_temp.clone();
                    });
                }
                prev_temp.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_node(temp_val, temp_next);
                });
            } else {
                let mut val: Option<T> = None;
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    val = Some((**node).borrow_mut().find_left_none());
                });
                self.value = val.unwrap();
            }
        } else {
            if value > self.value {
                self.right.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
                });
            } else {
                self.left.as_mut().map(|node| {
                    (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug + Clone> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T) {
        if self.root.is_none() {
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, None, None, None))));
        } else {
            let mut prev = self.root.clone();
            self.root.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().insert_value(value, prev);
            });
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T) {
        if !self.root.is_none() {
            self.root.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().delete_node(value);
            });
        }
    }

    fn print_tree(&self) {
        if !self.root.is_none() {
            self.root.as_ref().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow().print_tree();
            });
        } else {
            println!("empty");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::new();
    tree.insert_value(5);
    tree.insert_value(1);
    tree.insert_value(7);
    tree.insert_value(4);
    tree.insert_value(5);
    tree.print_tree();
}
```

as you define the return value of find_left_none to T which is not a reference type, you have to clone the value before return from the method

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to *destroy* part of the node, but you only have a mutable reference to it.  Either `self.value` must be able to be moved (which means the entire struct is now "dead" (if part of it moves, the whole thing is gone) and thus you need to pass `self` to the function not `&mut self` to do that) or the `value` field must be able to be copied (`Copy` trait, and a constraint on what you can hold).

So are you trying to destroy the current node when you return the contents?  By context, probably not, it seems like you want the `value` of the node returned, hence `T` being the return value.  So you either need to explicitly [`std::clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) it, or you need to return a reference to it, which means lifetimes.

I suggest reading through [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) for inspiration and assistance.  In particular, the first [Pop](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-pop.html) chapter, as well as the lifetimes one in [Iter](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-iter.html)

For your program, change the following:

```rust
impl<T: Clone + Ord + Debug> Node<T> {

// Snip

    fn find_left_none(&mut self) -> T {
        if (self.left.is_none() && self.right.is_none()) {
            let mut value = &self.value;
            self.prev.as_mut().map(|node| {
                (**node).borrow_mut().set_prev_none(value);
            });
            return self.value.clone();
        }else {
            return (**self.left.as_mut().unwrap().borrow_mut()).borrow_mut().find_left_none();
        }
    }

// Snip

impl<T: Clone + Ord+Debug> Tree<T> {
```

I hope that helps explain what else you needed and why.